# why can't I use element_text() in an ifelse()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How come I can't return an element_text()

```
> ifelse(TRUE,element_text(size=20),element_text(size=10))
[[1]]
NULL
```

but I can do this?

```
> element_text(size=20)
List of 8
 $ family    : NULL
 $ face      : NULL
 $ colour    : NULL
 $ size      : num 20
 $ hjust     : NULL
 $ vjust     : NULL
 $ angle     : NULL
 $ lineheight: NULL
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "element" "element_text"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just not in the way you're trying to use it:

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group)) + 
    geom_boxplot() + 
    theme(legend.text = element_text(size=ifelse(TRUE, 20, 10)))
```

It has to do with the `if` `else` you're using (`ifelse`) that's vectorized.  I think you're after `if(){}else{}` as in:

```
ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group)) + 
    geom_boxplot()+ 
    theme(legend.text = if(TRUE){element_text(size=20)} else {element_text(size=10)})
```

though I really wouldn't format it this way but kept it to one line to allow comparison to your method.

The problem isn't `ggplot2` but your use of `ifelse`.  Check out `?ifelse` and the documentation says:

```
 ‘ifelse’ returns a value with the same shape as ‘test’ which is
 filled with elements selected from either ‘yes’ or ‘no’ depending
 on whether the element of ‘test’ is ‘TRUE’ or ‘FALSE’.
```

In your question you show the output of `element_text(size=10)` that does not resemble `test` in structure.

Comment: Hey Tyler -- Congrats on hitting 10k!